# Maximum Length of Octet String allowed to send from SNMP Agent using LWIP

Tags: snmp, asn.1, mib, lwip, xilinx-edk

I am trying to implement SNMP agent on a device using LWIP Library in Xilinx SDK.

I successfully implemented the agent and got the agent running over my device to respond to commands (snmpget, snmpset,snmpwalk).

But if a OID has to return an octet string of length > 255, the agent behaves suspiciously.
when i tried to pass the octet string of length >255, i recieve no data on that oid and agent gets disconnected after that and will not repsond to any furthur commands.

snmp octet strings of length <255 are correctly received with no problem (no issues)..
I wonder does LWIP SNMP Agent has limitation on the size of the octet string..??

Comment: What data type is the object defined as in the MIB?

Comment: Its defined as OCTET STRING.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution...!!!

in the file src\lwip-1.4.0\src\core\snmp\msg_in.c , which processes the incoming messages is converting the length of string from u16_t to u8_t. It indicates the range has now deprecated to (0-255). So the problem.

I changed the u8_t's which are restricting me from processing octet strings of lenght > 255 to u16_t's.

Now the LWIP Library is able to handle message of length > 255..

Thanks..!!!

Comment: Follow this link to know more about the issue...!! https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?43790

Answer (score 1):

Objects defined as octet strings are typically limited to 255 bytes, either directly,

```
    SYNTAX               OCTET STRING (SIZE (0..255))
```

or indirectly by using something like DisplayString

```
    SYNTAX               DisplayString
```

which is in turn limited to 255 bytes.

```
DisplayString ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION 
    DISPLAY-HINT         "255a" 
    STATUS                current 
    DESCRIPTION          "Represents textual information taken from the NVT ASCII..."
    SYNTAX                OCTET STRING (SIZE (0..255))
```

Take a look at [RFC 2578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578) and [2579](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2579). You can define an object with a larger size, but bear in mind that SNMP isn't meant to transfer large sets of data.

Comment: I Agree with you..
But there was no limit specified in my MIB. My issue is, When i try to send data of size suppose 300, the program reads it as 44(300-256) and only 44 Characters in the octet string are being read or displayed.

The issue is not with the MIB's and its with the LWIP Library code. If u have already worked with LWIP Library and Let me know if you are able to Transfer an OCTET String >255.